# Tool for translating chomosome, index numbers to sequence information

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing

Is there a tool which allows me to transform information in the form (chromosome number, start index, end index) to sequence information? For example, something like (6, 43770819, 43770841) should yield GACCCCCTCCACCCCGCCTCCGG as this is the relevant bases on the 6th chromosome.

A command line executable is preferred, although a web-based service is also fine. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: I think this should be possible with Biomart.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small script to do that. Basically you just have to print a string from position-x to position-y. Explaining how to do that is not really on-topic here.

From available tools you can use [**`getfasta`**](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html) from the **`bedtools`** package. This requires a [**`BED`**](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html) file, or a [**`GTF`**](http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html) file  as an input. The three column format as in your question will also work but usually the orientation (`+/-`) is also important to fetch the right sequence; otherwise all sequences would be fetched from the `+` strand only. `GTF` format is a bit different: the three columns in your question would be the first fourth and fifth column in the `GTF`. Seventh column holds the orientation.

```
bedtools getfasta [OPTIONS] -fi <input FASTA> -bed <BED/GFF/VCF> -fo <output FASTA>
```

(or):

```
getFastaFromBed [OPTIONS] -fi <input FASTA> -bed <BED/GFF/VCF> -fo <output FASTA>
```

There is another one called [**`gffread`**](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/file_formats/#extracting-transcript-sequences) which comes with the `tophat` package.

`gffread` takes a `GTF/GFF` file as an input and gives you a fasta file of sequences corresponding to the positions listed in the `GTF` file. The third column (feature) should be `exon` or `transcript` as this tool was actually designed to extract transcript sequences.

```
gffread -w transcripts.fa -g /path/to/genome.fa transcripts.gtf
```